# How to avoid white space after logo for navbar?

Tags: bootstrap-4

```css
.navcolor {
    background-color: #ffffff !important;
}

.logoWidth {
    height:  100% !important;
    width:   23.1% !important;
    margin: -1% 0% 0% 23.3% !important;
    padding: 0% 0% 0% 0% !important;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light navcolor bg-light">
    <a class='space' href="https://dev.jillako.com/en/flights">
        <img class='logoWidth' src="/assets/logo.png" alt="">
    </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
          <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Flights</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Hotels</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Offers</a>
          </div>
        </div>
</nav>
```

I am trying to create a Navbar with bootstrap 4, so first I put a logo inside the anchor tag. Next I started keeping Home, About Us, like that
But white space is coming between anchor tag and home? How to resolve this problem please help me with this issue?

Comment: As you can see the width you have mentioned in `%`.That's causing the issue.  Give it in `px` as per your requirement. Below is the snippet for the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify `width:**px` to your navbar-logo `<img>` and you can use `class="ml-auto"` to align list to the right side

```
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light navcolor bg-light">
            <a class='space' href="https://dev.jillako.com/en/flights">
                <img class='logoWidth' src="/assets/image.jpg"
                    style="width:100px">
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup"
                aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
                <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Flights</a>
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Hotels</a>
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Offers</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Comment: Hi Manoj, I already accepted your answer, but my reputation is only 1 Infact today only I created Stack overflow account that's why it is showing like this Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: Accepting means there will be a ticket mark below upvote. When you click on it, it will turn into green. You need 15reputations for upvote. For accepting answer reputations are not a must.